# How can I add loading spinner while fetching data on react app?

Tags: reactjs

How to add loading spinner while fetching. I want to add loading spinner on fetch data on my react app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react `Suspense and lazy` for it. here below is a code example.

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from "react";

import Loading from "./loading";
const Loaded = lazy(() => import("./loaded"));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <Loaded />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

you can read mode about the suspense here [suspense](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html)

here is sandbox Link [sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dewdney-7d0cz3?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a loading state based on how you are fetching the data for example if you are fetching data using `axios` you need to set the loading to true in the beginning of your fetch function and set it to false on receiving data or on error.

```
const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchFunction = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    .
    .
    .
    if (data || error) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  if (loading) return <Loading />;

  return <Data />;
};
```